# elisp `trace-function` not producing trace

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp, trace

I am trying to trace a function in emacs lisp. I am trying to use `trace-function` and friends, but no trace is produced. The `*trace-output*` buffer gets created, but nothing is written in it.

Here is a minimal example of the problem:

```
(progn
  (require 'trace)
  (untrace-all)
  (defun f () 'hello)
  ;(trace-function 'f)
  ;(trace-function-background 'f)
  (trace-function-foreground 'f)
  (f))
```

Executing this from within `*scratch*` returns `'hello`, but not trace information is written to either `*trace-output*` or `*scratch*`.
I have tried it with each of the three trace functions above without success.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I get trace information to be produced?

Comment: Your test works when I try it (in `emacs-24.4 -Q`), so there seems to be some info missing.

Comment: @Stefan I am in 25 but I just tested with `emacs -Q` and it worked, so the real question is what package or setting is known to interfere with `function-trace` :(

Comment: Fwiw I have a number of packages but I do not do heavy customization. I mainly just use the customize options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package trace.el defines the global variable `inhibit-trace`, which is initially nil.
However, entering the debugger set `inhibit-trace` to `'t`,
which remains in effect until the debugger is explicitly quit.
Simply closing the `*Backtrace*` buffer does not exit the debugger.

My problem was that I had entered the debugger earlier in my sesion and not quit it explicitly.

This behaviour deserves to be better known :)